# How to find which ASPX files actually reference JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

Our ASP.Net project includes date.js (http://www.datejs.com/) in all of the .ASPX pages.

This script, however, throws exceptions during debugging even if page doesn't explicitly use it. So in all newly created .ASPX pages I don't include it unless it is actually needed.

Is there a way to find out what .ASPX pages **actually reference** functions from that .JS file (as opposed to just including this file)? For C# files I could just remove file from the project and see if there are any build errors. Is there a similar approach for .JS files?

**I am looking for an approach that doesn't require having to browse to each and every page on the site.**

Comment: assuming the aspx spits out html, search http logs for the script's URL, then check the referrer of those urls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193859/asp-net-catch-referenced-script-file-exceptions Perhaps you might use a logging framework?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firefox firebugger. Go to its script tab locate the code related to date.js and set a debug breakpoint, now try surfing around your site and you will see which pages are using it.

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't want to do - having to visit each page of the website. This is why I posted this question.

Comment: JavaScript is eventbased. You have to fire an event inside the script file you want to monitor.